# Long delay on contacting service on localhost using /etc/hosts entry

Tags: networking, osx-lion

I have a web server running on my local machine and when I perform a cURL request against it using the `localhost` address it executes very fast. However, when I add an /etc/hosts like

`127.0.0.1 test.local`

and then perform the same cURL request:

`curl -I http://test.local:3002/images/logo.png`

it delays for a solid 2-3 seconds. Changing the cURL request back to `localhost` again yields no delay.

This is reproducible every single time.

I've tried running the slow request under `dtruss` to see if I can find a system call that is causing the delay. Nothing out of the ordinary shows up.

I've tried making a dummy service via `netcat` that just returns `HTTP/1.0 200 OK` so I can guarantee the issue is not really due to my web server. Again, no difference: `localhost` is fast as you'd expect and `test.local` delays.

At this point I think there is somehow a DNS issue. That is, `/etc/hosts` is NOT being consulted first, that is, my upstream DNS is being checked, which fails, then `/etc/hosts` is being consulted which finally works.

Is this possible? Is `OS X Lion` somehow consulting my `/etc/hosts` later in the resolver chain?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I figured it out. I found this comment on a blog post:

> The matter is Lion handles .local TLD differently because it’s
>   reserved for some Multicast DNS features (used by Bonjour). The only
>   way i found to solve this issue is using a different TLD for
>   development hosts (ie: .dev). It works fine for me, hope it’s gonna be
>   helpful to others!

Switching my development domain to end in `.dev` works fine.

tl;dr - dont use `.local` for development domains in Lion.

Comment: You should add that if you add the IP6 line to `hosts` (`::1 test.local`), it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

OSX lion has this known bug. It would consult the DNS server first before using /etc/hosts entries. This behavior is only found in OSX lion and is not found in snow leopard, or even in tiger.

Possible options:

- Install DNSMasq
- Wait for patch from macosx
- <strike>Use snow leopard for the time being</strike>

Also see http://www.justincarmony.com/blog/2011/07/27/mac-os-x-lion-etc-hosts-bugs-and-dns-resolution/ for more details. It's well covered there.